A ring attached to an irreducible variety have the same fractional fields
I have a trouble to prove the following:
Let V be an irreducible algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Then for any open $U$ in $V$, $k(U):=Frac(\Gamma (U,\mathcal{O}_{V}))=Frac(\Gamma (V,\mathcal{O}_{V}))=:k(V)$ where $Frac(A)$ is the fractional field of an integral domain $A$. 
I already know that $U$ is dense in $V$. Thus, the restriction map $k[V]\rightarrow k[U]$ is injective hence $k(V) \subset k(U)$. How can I prove that $k(U)\subset k(V)$? Is there any canonical way to extend a function $f \in k(U)$ to $\tilde{f}\in k(V)$? Or, is there any other way to prove the statement above?
Edit: I already prove the theorem for the affine case: If $V$ and $U$ are affine, then their function fields are same.
Edit: Finally, I made it!! For an affine open covering $\bigcup_{i}V_{i}$ of $V$, let $\bigcup_{j}W_{ji}$ be an affine open covering of $U\cap V_{i}$. Then $Frac \mathcal{O}(U)=Frac(\bigcap_{i,j}\mathcal{O}(W_{ji}))=\bigcap_{i,j}Frac\mathcal{O}(W_{ji})=\bigcap_{i}Frac\mathcal{O}(V_{i})=Frac\mathcal{O}(V).$
Thanks for @notime and @ClemensB !!
 Edit: Someone dumb guy edited my question :) As @notime mentioned, $Frac$ does not commute with $\cap$. But, $ \mathcal{O}(U)=\bigcap_{i,j}\mathcal{O}(W_{ji})=\bigcap_{i}\mathcal{O}(V_{i})=\mathcal{O}(V)$ hence $k(U)\subset k(V)$, as desired.
 Edit: This guy is dumb too. I will try another way to  prove this..

Why is $Frac(\bigcap_{i,j}\mathcal{O}(W_{ji}))=\bigcap_{i,j}Frac\mathcal{O}(W_{ji})$? For example, consider $k[x],k[\frac{1}{x}]\subset k(x)$. We have $Frac(k[x]\cap k[\frac{1}{x}])=Frac(k)=k \neq Frac(k[x])\cap Frac(k[\frac{1}{x}])=k(x)$

As others have noted, the statement you are trying to prove is incorrect --- you need to delete the $Frac(Γ(V,\mathcal{O}_V))$. Then it becomes a statement about open affines, which you understand.

As @notime has pointed out, you have to be careful with your definition. I do not know where you take the definition of the fraction field from, but depending on that your statement might be trivial (or not). Hence, I'd ask you to first double check and clarify the definition that you are using.
E.g. in Vakil's notes, the field $k(V)$ would be defined as stalk of $\mathcal{O}_V$ at the generic point of $V$, and it is an easy exercise that on every affine open subset $U \subseteq V$ this agrees with taking the fraction field of the underlying ring $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_U)$. In this case, your statement is more or less a consequence of the definition.
EDITED/CORRECTED: If, however, you work with Hartshorne's definition (p. 16), then you would define $k(V)$ as the set of germs of regular functions defined on open subsets of $V$ (modulo equality on a common open subset). You should visualize these as functions that are defined everywhere on $V$ except on a closed subset. But this "except on a closed subset" is your saviour, because you need not really extend functions. Hence, you can "identically" identify $f \in k(U)$ in $k(V)$. If two elements $f_1, f_2 \in k(U)$ agree in $k(V)$, then they agree as functions on a small neighborhood contained in $U$ where they are both defined. But this is exactly the relation you modded out in the definition. Hence your claim becomes trivial.
Finally, if you are working with Milne's notes, then see my comment.
Comment: Bridging the gap between these (fortunately not contradictory) approaches is not necessarily a trivial thing.

I'm studying with Milne‘s book. What I studied is close to the second definition, but I'm not good enough to understand your answer yet. I will definitely come back and thank you when I study more and understand your answer.

Hm, if you are studying with Milne, then your claim should follow immediately from the definition: On page 113 of his November 2023 notes on algebraic geometry Milne defines the function field of $V$ as the the fraction field of k[U] for any affine open subvariety $U$ of $V$.

@ImBear: Understandably, you could not follow my explanations, because they were nonsense (at least the Hartshorne part). I have made an edit/correction. It is still somewhat minimal in detail, but my comment on Milne's approach should be the relevant part anyways.

If $V$ is proper over $k$, then $\Gamma(V,\mathscr{O}_V)=k$. However, $Frac(\Gamma(V,\mathscr{O}_V))=k$ may not equal $Frac(\Gamma(U,\mathscr{O}_U))$. For example, let $V=\mathbb{P}_{k}^1$ and $U=\mathbb{A}_{k}^1$.

I haven't defined the regular functions of projective space yet. I will definitely thank you when I learn it and understand your answer.
